# How to exit javascript script tags early?

Tags: javascript, web-frontend

I have a page with a bunch of .... sections. In one of them, I get half way through it and decide I want to stop, and not run the rest of the contents of this script tag - but still run the other code segments on the page. Is there any way to do this *without* wrapping the entire code segment in a function call?

for example:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    console.log('1 start');
    /* Exit here */
    console.log('1 end');
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    console.log('2 start');
    console.log('2 end');
</script>
```

which should produce the output

```
1 start
2 start
2 end
```

and NOT `1 end`.

The obvious answer is to wrap the script in a function:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    (function(){
        console.log('1 start');
        return;
        console.log('1 end');
    })();
</script>
```

Although this is usually the best approach, there are cases where it is not suitable. So my question is, what OTHER way can this be done, if any? Or if not, why not?

Comment: Exit without a condition?

Comment: I agree with @artm's thoughts - given that you (apparently) want to exit without a condition, surely you could just remove the `console.log('1 end');` line from the script block! No doubt there is more to this, so I would suggest you add a bit more detail as to _why_ you are trying to exit the js block. Ultimately though I suspect the best approach will be around designing and structuring your code - the use of inline script blocks doesn't really count in this respect ;)

Comment: @NathanRussell I'm not sure you grasp the concept of an "example"... the code above is not actual production code; it is just there to illustrate the case. In an actual production system, the "1 end" part might be something you want to execute sometimes and not others, or it might be being included by another file that you can't modify, or some other case. I don't know what the situation will be where this is necessary; I am asking mostly out of curiosity, and because I think it is a good question to have on SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the break statement :

```js
breakCode : {
  document.write('1 start');
  /* Exit here */
  break breakCode;
  document.write('1 end');
}
```

With a label reference, the break statement can be used to jump out of any code block

---

*Reference*

- [break MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break)

Comment: Wow, the return of goto... didn't see that coming.

Comment: Note: this only exists from the `{...}` block, not the entire script that might define more functions etc. (unless those functions are defined within the block, but that makes them complicated to access)

Answer (score 1):

One way of achieving what you want (stopping execution of a given script block, without wrapping it in a function), is to throw an error.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    console.log('1 start');
    throw new Error();
    console.log('1 end');
</script>
```

Of course the downside of this is that it will result in a error being logged to the console.

Comment: This won't work because his second `<script>` tag won't run then.

Comment: Yes it will - I double checked with a test before I wrote my answer (on Chrome at least)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the script tag using the `throw` approach (mentioned in [@knolleary's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30641642/11950764)), but without throwing an error message in the console, here's a hacky way of doing it:

```html
<script>
  console.log("This will get logged to console.");
  window.onerror = () => { window.onerror=undefined; return true; }
  throw 0;
  console.log("This won't.");
</script>
```

That code just captures the error with `window.onerror` (returning `true` hides the error).

You could of course create a global function if you need to use it often:

```html
<script>
  function scriptReturn() {
    window.onerror = () => { window.onerror=undefined; return true; }
    throw 0;
  }
</script>
...
<script>
  console.log("This will get logged to console.");
  scriptReturn();
  console.log("This won't.");
</script>
```

If you need to use `window.onerror` elsewhere in your code you can use `addEventListener`:

```js
window.addEventListener("error", function(e) { ... })
```